# Identification electronic component (Canon stock)

Tags: diodes, identification

What is the part number and manufacturer of this component?

Top mark: -15 7R :

This component comes from Canon stock.

Canon code: WA1-0027-000

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Likely an ordinary diode or Zener diode, which you can test with a power supply, resistor and voltmeter.